# how to block a user without permission to a resource in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm building a api and i'm really stuck here trying figure out how to properly block users without permissions to given resource, i already created a table users, roles, role_user, permissions and role_permissions. when i searched on google, i saw several ways of do it, using `Gate` inside `AuthServiceProvider`, or using middleware. my question is: what's the best way of do it in laravel with API? in my company the users can have one or more roles, and the users can have a individual permission too. Also, tried some ACL packages but all them have some specific problems, like: some methods are deprecated in laravel 5.5, or docs are not clear of how to use the class. tried do the logic by myself too but i'm stuck in the question of how to block the access to the resource if the user not have given permission.

Comment: what's wrong with using a middleware?

Comment: You can check https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#permissions package.

Comment: i don't have any problem with middlewares, my problem is build the logic to block the resource when the permission match the resource url

Answer (score 0):

Laravel it self blocks access for any resource out of public folder (Storage Folder).
In addition to that you can create a middleware that checks the user requesting the route and decides to return or not the resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware for this purpose. Checkout https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware for more information

Once you have created the middleware, you can do :

```
 Route::group(['middleware'=>'yournewmiddlewarename'], function() {
    Route::resource("url", ...);
 }
```